# .DataSource outputs a duplicate list?

Tags: asp.net, datasource

When the user selects a value from the drop down list and clicks on the button, the value is added to a second list (which is also displayed on screen).

The problem being when the user clicks on the button, the selected value is added to the second list however the drop down list is duplicated and added to the original drop down list.

So we have 1, 2, 3 in the original drop down, User selects '1' and presses the button.
'1' is added to the second list and displayed on screen BUT when the user clicks on the drop down it now contains 2, 3, 1, 2, 3

Iv went through my code with break point and I think it has something to do with the .dataSource.

```
protected void UpdatePage()
{
   int Id = System.Convert.ToInt32(Id.Value);

   List<Contractor> allContractors = new List<Contractor>();
   ClarkeDBDataContext db = new ClarkeDBDataContext();

   allSubContractors = (from BoqContractors in db.BOQ_Contractors
                        where BoqContractors.Bill_Of_Quantity_id == tempBoqId
                        select BoqContractors.Contractor).ToList();

   repeaterShowContractorName.DataSource = allContractors;
   repeaterShowContractorName.DataBind();

   IEnumerable<Sub> availableContractors = 
       (from sc in db.Contractors
        select sc).ToList().Except(allContractors);

    //i've tried to set it to null to test it, but to no avail
    DropDownListContractors.DataSource = null;
    DropDownListContractors.DataSource = availableContractors;
    DropDownListContractors.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original values exist in the ddl because of ViewState and Postback. The ddl is repopulated on Postback. This is why the original values are there.

I am not sure why you need to reget the data from the db in this use case. If you do need to 
refresh the list from the db, simply call `DropDownListContractors.Clear()` before setting the `DataSource`. This will clear out the list.

**BUT**, like I stated earlier, I don't think you need to rebind the ddl from the db. Simply remove these lines from your code (when posting back) and it should work as you want it:

```
   IEnumerable<Sub> availableContractors = 
       (from sc in db.Contractors
        select sc).ToList().Except(allContractors);

    //i've tried to set it to null to test it, but to no avail
    DropDownListContractors.DataSource = null;
    DropDownListContractors.DataSource = availableContractors;
    DropDownListContractors.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the VB side, DropDownListContractors.ClearSelection() isn't enough, if you have no data selected, in my case i don't have any, but still need to clear the data in the list.

If i just use DropDownListContractors.Items.Clear(), it will clear data already in my list, set in my aspx page. (i need to keep sometimes one or two row, along with databind data).

The only workaround i found is to add a condition in the pageload, weither or not the page has already got the source from our database. That data is less likely to change.:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
  'myComboBox.Items.Clear() 
  'Can't use this, i got one or two items i gotta keep from the aspx page
  'myComboBox.DataSource = Nothing 
  'DOESNT WORK
  myComboBox.DataSource = someSource
  myComboBox.DataBind()
End If
```

If i was with your case, i would just call items.clear() and add manualy the items i need back, in the .vb code behind.